# Comparação de BigDecimal retorna resultado inesperado

Tags: java, decimal

Em um dos meus métodos realizo a seguinte comparação, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal("100");
    exemplo(valor);

}

public static void exemplo(BigDecimal valor) {
    if (valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("50.000")) == 1 || valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("50.000")) == 0) {
        System.out.println("número maior");
    }
}
```

Passando como parâmetro o valor "100", o problema é que a class BigDecimal acaba considerando o valor "100" maior que o valor "50.000", tentei passar o valor como: "50.000.00" para tentar solucionar o problema, mas a classe não me permite fazer isso, alguma solução?

Comment: Mas 100 é maior do que 50. Poderia esclarecer melhor o que você pretende?

Comment: colocando como exemplo nosso dinheiro, estou comparando 100 reais com 50.000 mil, não tem como ser maior..

Comment: Não, você está comparando R$ 100 com R$ 50,000.

Comment: @bigown como assim, estou confuso agora estou fazendo alguma coisa errada?

Comment: @Emanoel Tentei esclarecer a confusão na resposta. Dê uma olhada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está, na verdade, comparando 100 com 50. Em inglês, o ponto separa a parte inteira da parte fracionária de um número em vez da vírgula.
Como indicado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29), o `BigDecimal` aceita números fracionários representados dessa forma em seu construtor. É o que você está fazendo sem ver.

Para fazer o que você pretende, compare com "50000".

Comment: Obrigado @Pablo Almeida

Answer (score 5):

O ponto é o separador decimal, então você está comparando 100 com 50 (50.000 lido "em português" é 50,000, ou simplesmente 50). Não use pontos para fazer separação de milhar. Na verdade isto não existe em programação. Veja:

```
public static void exemplo(BigDecimal valor) {
    if (valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("50000")) == 1 || valor.compareTo(new BigDecimal("50000")) == 0) System.out.println("número maior");
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente.

O motivo de não aceitar `50.000.00` é porque ele tem dois separadores decimais, ou para o que nós usamos aqui no Brasil, é como se tivesse duas vírgulas, o que um número não pode ter.

Eu imagino que no seu problema real está recebendo um valor como *string* e ele tem casas decimais. Aí você deve converter o valor para `BigDecimal` de acordo com o padrão que receber. É outra coisa completamente diferente.

```
public static void exemplo(BigDecimal valor) {
    try {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0", new DecimalFormatSymbols (new Locale ("pt", "BR")));
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        BigDecimal decimal = (BigDecimal)df.parse("50.000");
        if (valor.compareTo(decimal) == 1 || valor.compareTo(decimal) == 0) System.out.println("número maior");
        else System.out.println("número menor");
    } catch (ParseException e) { //só para facilitar, não faça isto
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2PRipU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dtdhrtqi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/BigDecimal.java).

Comment: Até existe, mas não com o ponto ou a vírgula. Java tem o `_` e C++ tem o `'`.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Comment: @Emanoel editei para colocar algo complementar que talvez você deseje.